# What is the reasoning behind the different return types in string::insert?

Tags: c++, stdstring

[Click here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) to see the functions. As you can see, all but the last three return a reference to the string. The 3rd last overload returns an iterator, which I am guessing (I may be wrong...) is because the iterator in the argument may become invalid after the insert operation.

What about the last two functions? Why are they not returning a reference to the string? Is there any reason behind this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all about ***history***. `std::string` is a thing that should not even exist in C++. Not because C++ shouldn't have a string class (it must have had tens of thousands when `std::string` was being worked on), but because the C++ standardization was meant to codify ***existing practice***, and there was no single string class that merely needed to be renamed to `std::string` in order to have a standardized string class. So it was "design by committee", something Stroustrup dreaded and, thus, the C++ standardization effort set out to avoid.
Nevertheless, the library working group never found a string class they liked, so they started to create their own, violating one of the major underlying principles of the standardization process.

And as if that wasn't enough, only months before the expected standardization of C++, Stroustrup ran into Stepanov and his ***STL***. A library of containers and algorithms was embarrassingly missing from the C++ standard, which is what I guess got Stroustrup interested in Stepanov's in the first place. The STL, while looking strange to all of us, who had so far been exposed to classic OO libraries only, had the unique advantage of ***combining*** a certain (if alien) ***elegance with efficiency***, something we all, at that point, thought of as not being combinable at all.
So Stroustrup lobbied for the inclusion of the STL into the standard, and ultimately succeeded, thereby delaying the standard by probably a whole year. (And aren't we thankful for this delay today! I mean, what would C++ be without the STL?!)
In the process, it was realized that ***`std::string` is a container***, too, so it was retroactively turned into a full-blown STL container by ***adding an STL container interface*** to its already quite bloated interface.

That is why `std::string` now has functions taking and returning indexes right besides those taking and returning iterators.

Answer (score 4):

The overloads to which you refer are consistent with the `insert()` operations for all the other standard containers. If you will, you can just treat a `string` as an opaque container of `char`s. Thus, if you have a generic algorithm that uses `insert()`, you can use it with any container *and* with `string` without ever changing your code.

It's the hallmark of a quality library to provide rich interfaces with least surprise (what should work does work), so I'd take this to be an instance thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because they're there to mimic other containers' insert behaviour, like [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

Answer (score 0):

That has to do with the string's bloated interface. The last two function overloads are the ones for standard STL containers. The others came from a time previous to adoption of the STL containers, where the string had its own different (bloated) interface.

Comment: "the last two" should be "the last three."

Answer (score 0):

The only natural point to return an iterator for would be the point of insertion. Now, when you add several characters they are added sequentially and the previous iterator is invalidated for every insert operation. This means that when you've actually added all the characters to the string you don't have a valid iterator for the point of insertion anymore.